# Secret hats - how to discover where they come from?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I recently earned a secret hat:

[image]

How do I know the reason why I earned it?

Comment: I think the point of the secret hats is that they are... ummm... [secret](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211707/214632).

Comment: Given who Chuck Yeager is, I would hazard a guess that this hat is for participating in Winter Bash early. But can you guess what my and Arthur's secret hats are for?

Comment: I was wondering the same about Johnny Three-Hats.

Comment: Hmm good one. The connection to the first pilot to break the speed of sound. Is there something, or things, you have been the first person to do, or achieve, very fast? You definitely broke some sort of barrier (maybe several) on that [Monty Hall problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/608957/monty-hall-problem-extended/608977#608977) around the same time you posted this. My hat goes off to you there!

Comment: First to answer a question?

Comment: But ... Look at the Mean Square in Chuck Yeager helmet. That's a matching hat!

Comment: The idea of a secret hat defeats the values of a math site.  Math should be transparent.  Secret hats suggest a team of unknown elites who are secretly laughing at all of us for unknown reasons.  It is off-putting.

Answer (score 6):

Don't worry about why you earned something, **and** you don't know why you earned it. Instead, focus on the happiness it brings you :)

Comment: I also got spock ears and it brings me a lot of happiness.